# Go routine with channel deadlock

Tags: go

I just started to learn Go so please bear with me, I've tried to play around with Go routines and channels but are getting a deadlock somehow.

Here's the example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)


func main() {
    total := 2
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(total)

    ch := make(chan int)

    for idx := 0; idx < total; idx++ {
        fmt.Printf("Processing idx %d\n", idx)

        go func(idx int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            ch <- idx
        }(idx)
    }

    for val := range ch {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }

    fmt.Println("Wait")
    wg.Wait()
}
```

which throws the error

```
Processing idx 0
Processing idx 1
1
0
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Comment: side note: you mean *bear with*, not *bare with* — see https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1269/180540

Comment: Indeed I do ;) would be awkward if I meant the other one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range ch` reads from the channel until it is closed.

How many times do you call `close(ch)`?  When will the `for val := range ch` loop terminate?

---

When *should* you close the channel?  You have a lot of options here, but one way to do it is to add another goroutine:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}()
```

e.g., after spinning off all routines that will write-to-channel-then-call-`wg.Done()`, so that the channel is closed once all the writers are done writing.  (You can run this goroutine as soon as you've increased the `wg` count to account for all writers.)